# NGINX redirect to www in multi-domain environment

Tags: redirect, nginx, no-www

How can I redirect non-www to www in NGINX when the domain name is not predetermined? All the examples I've found show domain.com or example.com. I need to redirect for any domain. Any pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7947030/1544337) (works the same, just the other way around) or [Nginx rewrite non-www prefixed domain to www-prefixed domain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1629231/1544337)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one that got me going:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3766957/447516

```
if ($host ~* ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the default server to catch domains that are *not* specified in the `server_name` directives of your configuration.

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

will make that server catch non matching domain names (assuming the port is 80 on all interfaces).

This is a [clear explanation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names) of this behavior.

(not that before *nginx 0.8.21* `default` (not `default_server`)  has to be specified).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am listening on my IP since all domains are an alias for it. The CMS does all the switching.. Im going to try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1639549/447516 and post my results, it seems to logically be what I've been searching for. We'll see if it works.

Comment: The second answer seems like what you want "http://stackoverflow.com/a/1691116/2149092", but don't use the rewrite method, use the 301 return as specified in the third answer "http://stackoverflow.com/a/15517045/2149092" because it's less processing for nginx since it doesn't involve regex.